# Выборы и локализация

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, выборы

На странице выдвижения кандидата поясняющий текст сформулирован странно:

> Хорошие модераторы часто:
>   ► иметь достаточно высокую репутацию, указывающую на активное участие
>   ► интересоваться развитием сообщества на Мете
>   ► подавать пример, демонстрируя терпение и уважением к другим участникам сообщества
>   ► демонстрировать непостижимые черты, описанные в Теории модерации

Надо либо заменить "часто" на "должны", либо поменять форму глаголов.

---

На [странице выборов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/1):

> Срок выдвижения кандидатов до через 6 дней

C "до через" надо что-то делать. Да и вообще с этой фразой.

Как насчёт такого варианта?

> Выдвижение кандидатов закончится через 6 дней

---

Там же ещё один "до через":

> Выборы сейчас находятся на этапе выдвижения кандидатов. Срок выдвижения кандидатов до через 21 час.

---

Третий этап выборов - описание справа, третий абзац надо перевести:

> We will calculate the winners using [OpenSTV](http://www.openstv.org/) with the [Meek STV method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meek's_method#Meek.27s_method), which automatically weights users' votes in the way that does the most good for the candidates they have selected, in order of preference.

Обращаю внимание, что там две ссылки - хорошо бы и для них русские аналоги подобрать.

Comment: Через 6 дней было бы хорошо, но там нет даты начала (откуда 6 дней отсчитывать).

Comment: @avp, с текущего момента. Длительность вроде 7 дней, а указано 6, т. е. один прошёл уже.

Comment: А послезавтра? Реально останется 5. Или Вы предлагаете постоянно менять это число в тексте? Если кто-то будет это отслеживать, то решение годится.

Comment: @avp, часть с числом дней уже есть и уже работает. Я предлагаю только формулировку фразы исправить.

Comment: Нормальная формулировка, мне нравится.

Comment: Для первой ссылки не нужен русский аналог, это ссылка на сайт ПО. Вторая уже переведена: [Как подсчитываются голоса на выборах модераторов?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1999)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спасибо за найденные недочеты! 1) Поправил форму глаголов. 2) Изменил на «Срок выдвижения кандидатов истекает ...». Буду рад улучшить перевод если появятся улучшеная формулировка.

Comment: Оперативно :) Но я сюда ещё буду накидывать, по мере нахождения - думаю нет смысла на каждую фразу тему заводить.

Comment: Свежее дополнение.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я обновлял и эту строку тоже, еще в первый раз. На всякий случай обновил базу строк еще раз.

Comment: Строка внутри вкладки - по-прежнему старая. Речь точно о ней?

Comment: @Qwertiy Пожалуйста, подскажите, присутствует ли еще дефект перевода?

Comment: Нет, теперь всё хорошо

Comment: Обнаружился непереведённый кусок.

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо! Поправил.

Comment: А когда применится? Я по-прежнему английский вижу.

Comment: @Qwertiy Новые строки попадают на сайт после обновления версии движка (происходит несколько раз в день).

Comment: До сих пор по-английски - что-то совсем не похоже на несколько раз в день...