# Голосование продлится до через 8 дней

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, выборы

В самом низу [страницы выборов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election) видим такую картинку:

> [image: до через]

Сам исправлю, сам приму ;) Чтоб не забыть.

Comment: Думаешь, исправишь? Кажется, где-то уже были проблемы с этой фразой "до через"?

Comment: @Qwertiy есть [варианты](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2055/176217)... :-D или [вот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5091/176217) ещё.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Изменил текст перевода на следующий:

> Выборы сейчас находятся на этапе голосования. Голосование закончится $VotingEnds$.

Будет на сайте после обновления transifex и пересборки движка.

Comment: *Выборы сейчас находятся* - имхо, как-то пластмассово звучит. Может *Выборы сейчас на стадии голосования*? И [вики, как бы, согласна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B#.D0.A1.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.B4.D0.B8.D0.B8_.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.B1.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.BE_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.86.D0.B5.D1.81.D1.81.D0.B0)

Comment: @Anatol "этап" и "стадия" это одно и то же. Я вот подумываю "сейчас" скорее убрать, чем менять шило на мыло.

Comment: так я не о "этапах" и "стадиях", в основном, а о "находятся". Выборы не могут находиться нигде, находиться может процесс выборов. Сейчас тоже можно убрать, абсолютно согласен.

Comment: @Anatol слово "выборы" это и есть процесс в данном случае. Процесс, состоящий из нескольких стадий-этапов.

Comment: да нет, даже "процесс выборов находится" звучит неестественно, а "выборы находятся" - тем более. Естественным тут будет опустить слово "находится" в обоих случаях. Это будет "более лучше" :)

Comment: @Anatol "процесс выборов" это масло масленное. Вот на вашей вики "Выборы — это процедура...", далее "Процедура — взаимосвязанная последовательность действий...". Чем не процесс?

Comment: это не моя вики, а такая же общая, как и ваш стековерфлоу. объясню - "находиться" - значит находиться физически, в данном же случае это слово используется в значении "пребывать в состоянии", верно? так вот употребление "пребывать в состоянии" практически никогда не используется, например - вместо того, чтобы говорить "я пребываю в состоянии злости" мы говорим "я зол" и уж тем более никто не говорит "я нахожусь в состоянии злости". так же вместо "я нахожусь на этапе поиска смысла жизни" мы говорим "я в поиске" и так далее

Comment: @Anatol не хочу разводить тут флейм по пустякам, если хотите выслушать мнения лингвистов, предлагаю задать вопрос на [rus.se].

Comment: то есть вы не линвист? а чем же тогда руководствуетесь при принятии решения? и в соответствии с какими критериями "до через" не пустяк, а это пустяк? по принципу броскости? я тоже флейма не хочу, ваша позиция мне понятна

Comment: @Anatol есть ошибки очевидные, как "до через", а есть неочевидные (может и вовсе не ошибки). Всякую "тонкую настройку" можно проводить достаточно долго и мало кто вообще чего заметит, но если хочется — стоит обратиться к более сведущим людям.

Comment: @Anatol я согласен, что слово "находятся" можно убрать, но не согласен с аргументом через википедию. Вики - это не источник и не образец.

Comment: @Nick это не источник и не образец в академическом смысле, но вполне себе источник и образец в повседневном. Опять же, по аналогии с этим порталом - информация тут о технологиях исключительно справочная (субъективность, специфичность), тогда как всегда можно обратиться к первоисточникам (документациям, спецификациям).

Comment: Я тоже не считаю вики непоколебимым авторитетом, но и не считаться с ней нельзя